# How to convert strength to power in basketball?

Tags: strength, power

We have been lifting for strength with the 1x20RM program but now we are getting closer to pre-season and would like to start converting the strength to power.  How can i convert their strength to power?

Comment: "We" and "convert their strength"? I feel like a couple details are missing here.

Comment: @C.Lange It looks like he is a coach for Highschool basketball. I do agree though, I'm not really sure what he is asking. Perhaps, he is asking how to incorporate the new strength into more explosive sprints and jumps?

Comment: @EricWarburton -- ah, I see that now. Was on mobile before. For OP though, you had a previous question on good exercises that increase power. What would you like to know beyond that?

Comment: Power in which movement pattern? shooting, sprinting or jumping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exercise will always increase performance and strength in any sport such as basketball and futball as long as you are consistent and **complemented with good rest and nutrition.**

However, it is important to emphasize and it is that many people **exercise without a specific plan** and do not usually work certain parts of the body that are essential for an improvement in sports skills.

I recommend that you search for ***corrective exercises*** and how to avoid ***muscle amnesias*** which for the most part is what makes the difference between amateur players and high performance athletes.

Examples of this is to perform exercises in all physical planes ***(Sagittal, transverse and longitudinal)***. **Strength exercises** (explosive and isometric) and resistance, doing it well your sports fitness will be increased.

Visit https://www.nasm.org/continuing-education/fitness-specializations/corrective-exercise-specialist/what-is-corrective-exercise **For corrective exercises**

and https://www.acefitness.org/fitness-certifications/ace-answers/exam-preparation-blog/2863/the-planes-of-motion-explained/ for the ***planes of motion***

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I believe being able to connect your kinetic chain is important for power, in your context. You can first:

1. Identify which muscles are needed for that particular movement
2. Determine their role in that movement
3. The sequential initiation of those muscles

Trying to put into context. Say you want to jump higher, you train the quads and glutes. But that doesn’t necessary equate to a higher jump height. Using the above:

1. Quads, glutes, calves, and core
2. Quads to achieve knee extension during lift off, glutes to get hip extension, calves for better explosiveness and jump height, core to provide stability and connect your kinetic chain
3. Arm swing, anterior pelvic tilt to eccentrically load the glutes, bent knees into squatting position, arm string, hip and knee extension

Training for specificity and learning how to connect the chain will be effective